# Method checks if String matches Pattern not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a method checkIfStringIsValidWord(String) which checks if a String is a 'valid word' in my make-believe Language. A 'valid word' is a word that is only composed of the substring "ba" and/or "fi" and/or "ifi" (bafi, bafifiba, ifibaifibaifififi are all valid words). Empty/Null Strings cannot be passed as parameters.

The method works for a lot of words but is returning false for the valid word: "babafibafifiba".
What is wrong with the regex I have? Help is appreciated.

```
public boolean checkIfStringIsValidWord(String word) {
    return word.matches("(ifi)*(ba)*(fi)*(ifi)*(ba)*(fi)*");
}
```

Comment: this still returns false, for given word but you have helped me reach the answer `matches("(ifi|fi|ba)*")` works with all my test cases (might still be wrong).

Comment: Your example has 3 separate ba's, the regex just 2 separate ba's. Also your regex tends to be slow.

Comment: Sorry, it is `^(?:i?fi|ba)*$` of course. I made the wrong `i` optional.

Answer (score 0):

Correct function:

```java
public boolean wordValid(String word) {
    return word != null && word.matches("(ifi|ba|fi)+");
}
```

This regex says that your word consists of pieces such as ifi, ba, fi and + means that at least one piece must be present.